# Regex - matching a ZIP code out from a String sentence in JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble to understand regular expression in JAVA. I'm trying to get a ZIP code from a List. I set my regex like this below.

```
\b([0-9]{5})(?:-[0-9]{4})?\b
```

List example:

```
    22193 
    22192-2222
    .22193
    hello this is .221938
    hello this is .22012
    hello this is 22193
    22193 hello
    221931
    22193.2222
```

When I used the .matcher(string) and looping the list above, I received this results below.

```
22193 -----MATCH
22192-2222------MATCH
.22193-----MATCH
hello this is .221938
hello this is .22012 ----MATCH
hello this is 22193---- MATCH
22193 hello  -----MATCH
221931
22193.2222 ---- MATCH
```

The issue is that its matching with numbers that have decimals before and after. (the same with special characters like \, $, %, etc.).
I want this results

```
22193 ---------MATCH
22192-2222 ------MATCH
.22193
hello this is .221938
hello this is .22012
hello this is 22193 -----MATCH
22193 hello ---- MATCH
221931
22193.2222
```

How can I match a string that does not have special characters in between and before/after the zip code? Please can you insist me? I've trying to play it around in regextester.com but no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you could do is the following:

```
((?<=\s|^)\d{5}(?=\s|$|-\d{4}(?=\s|$)))(?:-\d{4}(?=\s|$))?
```

See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BV6hlp/1/)

---

- `(` - Starting 1st capturing group.

  - `(?<=\s|^)` - Positive lookbehind for either a space-character *or* a start string ancor.
  - `\d{5}` - Match exactly five digits ranging 0-9.
  - `(?=\s|$|-\d{4}(?=\s|$))` - A positive lookahead to match either a space-character *or* an end-string ancor *or* an hyphen followed by exactly four digits ranging 0-9 with a nested positive lookahead to check for either a space-character or end-string ancor.
- `)` - Closing capture group 1.
- `(?:` - Starting a non-capture group

  - `-\d{4}` - Matching an hyphen followed by exactly four digits ranging 0-9.
  - `(?=\s|$)` - A positive lookahead for either a space-character or end-string ancor.
- `)?` - Closing non-capture group and making it optional.

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this regex. I have used your mentioned special characters.

```
(?<!(?:\.|\$|\%|\\))\b(?:[0-9]{5})(?:-[0-9]{4})?\b(?!(?:\.|\$|\%|\\))
```

Check the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/C8JK0D/1)